# How to mount all bucket in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: gcsfuse

From document https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse, when use FUSE GCS there is only mound predefine bucket to the specified path.

In case I have many buckets, show how I can mount all buckets as root directory can access or create any bucket as the directory?

Answer (score 1):

gcsfuse doesn't support mounting multiple buckets in a single process, nor does it support creating buckets for you. You'll need to create buckets in the usual way outside gcsfuse, then run one gcsfuse process per desired bucket.